# Why is one of my cards disappearing on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm making my first steps in mobile web design. I have write this html for desktop size:

[image]

But when I press Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome to see the size in mobile I lost the first card, Free Willy.

[image]

Is it possible make this with flex-wrap??

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.card {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: all in ease;
}

.card-image {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.boat1 {
  background-image: url ('../img/FreeWilly/FreeWi3mini.jpg');
}

.boat2 {
  background-image: url('./img/ Xu/X4Mini.jpg');
}

.boat3 {
  background-image: url('../img/xalana.jpeg');
}

.boat4 {
  background-image: url('../img/Victorymini.jpg');
}

.card a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}

.reja {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reja">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Free Willy</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat1">
      </div>
      <p>Lancha de 38 pés convertida para pescaria em alto mar.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Yu</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat2">
      </div>
      <p>Barco robaleiro de 7 metros, com Painel na popa, projetado para até 4 pescadores + guia.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Xalana</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat3">
      </div>
      <p>Barco robaleiro de 7 metros, com Painel na popa, projetado para até 4 pescadores + guia.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Victory</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat4"></div>
      <p>26 pés ,painel e controle central, com espaço para pesca em volta do barco todo,
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Notice how I've updated your post to more clearly present the problem. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for posting tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your class "container". Just like that, and you will see free willy again. Flex-wrap is a good practice to begin with responsive website.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.03);
  transition: all in ease;
}

.card-image {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.boat1 {
  background-image: url ('../img/FreeWilly/FreeWi3mini.jpg');
}

.boat2 {
  background-image: url('./img/ Xu/X4Mini.jpg');
}

.boat3 {
  background-image: url('../img/xalana.jpeg');
}

.boat4 {
  background-image: url('../img/Victorymini.jpg');
}

.card a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}

.reja {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reja">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Free Willy</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat1">
      </div>
      <p>Lancha de 38 pés convertida para pescaria em alto mar.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Yu</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat2">
      </div>
      <p>Barco robaleiro de 7 metros, com Painel na popa, projetado para até 4 pescadores + guia.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Xalana</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat3">
      </div>
      <p>Barco robaleiro de 7 metros, com Painel na popa, projetado para até 4 pescadores + guia.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Victory</h2>
      <div class="card-image boat4"></div>
      <p>26 pés ,painel e controle central, com espaço para pesca em volta do barco todo,
      </p>
      <a href="#">Agenda</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```